# Add FileSystemEventHandler dynamically to FileSystemWatcher

Tags: c#, dynamic, module, filesystemwatcher, eventhandler

I am trying to make a windows service that can retrieve a list of "hotfolders" from a database table where all the info to FileSystemWatcher is included (scanning dir, file filter and so on).

But this takes me to the problem when i want to add the Created event handler to the FileSystemWatcher.

```
id  hotFolderName   directory   fileFilter  engineModule    includeSubdirs
1   PDFinvoices     c:/pdf      *.pdf       pdfModule       0
2   FlatFiles       c:/flat     *.txt       flatModule      1
```

So for each of the posts in the table it creates a FileSystemWatcher with the above settings but my problem is when i want to tie the EventHandler to it. How do i do it dynamically?

So in this case i would like to do:

```
fileSystemWatcher1.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(dbResultSet("engineModule"));
```

Is this possible to do somehow? I know that i need to have a function named pdfModule as well, but thats no problem. I just want to be able to add more modules but never have to change the syntax above.

And pdfModule in this case might not be in the main class, i was thinking i make one class for each module. Like pdfModule, flatModule ... u get the point.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create your own file monitor class and wrap watcher properties in that and for event you can handle it like below

```
this.yourwatcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(this.yourwatcher_Created);
this.yourwatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
```

In service start event you can get all info from DB and can do something like below

```
this.filemonitor[0] = new CustomFileMonitor("pdfModule");  // This will configure watcher properties for PDF file types and attach event.
this.filemonitor[0].Start();
```

Create new instance of your file monitor for each folder type.